# Radial position operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, definition, mathematics

While trying to find the expectation value of the radial distance $r$ of an electron in hydrogen atom in ground state the expression is:

$$\begin{aligned}\langle r\rangle &=\langle n \ell m|r| n \ell m\rangle=\langle 100|r| 100\rangle \\ &=\int r\left|\psi_{n \ell m}(r, \theta, \phi)\right|^{2} d V \end{aligned}$$

Since Hilbert space operators act on kets, What operator is $r$ in the expression:
$$\begin{aligned}\langle r\rangle &=\langle n \ell m|r| n \ell m\rangle=\langle 100|r| 100\rangle~? \end{aligned}$$

Is it a component of the position operator $\mathbf x$ that is related to the radial distance?

Does it act on kets as:

$$\hat{r}|r \theta \phi\rangle=r|r \theta \phi\rangle~?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gone awry at the end of your question, utilizing ambiguous/meaningless notation.

Here, it is best to use the caret $\hat {\mathbf v}$ to signify a unit vector, as in Sakurai-Napolitano (3.6.22,23),
$$
\langle {\mathbf x}|nlm\rangle = R_{nl}(r) Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)= R_{nl}(r) \langle \hat {\mathbf x}|l,m\rangle , 
$$
and *not* an operator, as in the punchline of your question: use another symbol for operators, instead.

Consequently, by inspection,
$$ \langle r\rangle   =\int r^2 dr ~~ r (R_{nl}(r))^2  ,  $$
since the $d\Omega$ integral factored out to 1.

The linear power of *r* in this expression is just just a c-number, the radial value (length) of the c-number vector
${\mathbf x}= r \hat {\mathbf x}$, since you are working in the coordinate representation.

If you *must* think of an operator with eigenvalue *r*, it is $\large \mathbb r$ s.t.
$$
{\large \mathbb r} ~ |{\mathbf x}\rangle= r  |{\mathbf x}\rangle ,
$$
and you could apply the machinery of Dirac's ket notation in the above, which, however, is superfluous, and, evidently, confusing here.

Comment: Thank you professor. I'm trying to work in both the wavefunction and dirac notation so that my basics get correct hence my wish to see the dirac notation. Also, Is it that, In general,  functions of operators are defined  such as below : 
  $$f(\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z})|x,y,z \rangle=f(x,y,z) |x,y,z \rangle$$ ? Here $f$ is a real valued function of variable $x, y, z$

Comment: In your answer above $|\hat{ 
   \mathbf   x}\rangle$ means $|\theta, \phi\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: But don’t use carets for operators here! This is the source of your confusion! I'd write your relation here as $f({\mathbb x}, {\mathbb y}, {\mathbb z})|x,y,z\rangle=  f(  x, y,z)|x,y,z\rangle$.

Comment: I cannot see why you say "This is the source of your confusion". I think I'm clear on operators and vectors. In my question can you please pin point the statement where I am confusing the notation so that I can learn from my mistake? Thank you professor :)

Comment: This is a straightforward question on Dirac notation and directional unit vectors, most sensibly depicted by carets. By giving them  (carets) double-duty as signifiers of operators, you make it impossible, if not inconceivable, to contemplate unit vector operators. I assume you can now  represent ${\mathbb r}$ in terms of $\mathbb x$, ...